# how to sinon stub an Error from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sinon

i got something like this (taking from http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-error-handling.html) :

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
});

schema.post('save', function(error, doc, next) {
  if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
    next(new Error('There was a duplicate key error'));
  } else {
    next(error);
  }
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', schema);
```

now i want to mock using sinon stub an exception during:

```
const person = new Person({ name: 'Val' }); 
person.save(); // <--- i want a mocked error to be passed to the schema.post middleware
```

how can i do that?

General information:
i got some class, MyDao, who haves a 'save' method, which returns person.save();

so i tried:

```
sinon.stub(MyDao.prototype, 'save', () => {
        throw new Error({name: 'MongoError', code: 11000}))};
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to stub the instance of object not the class.

```
const person = new Person({ name: 'Val' }); 
sinon.stub(person, 'save').throws({name: 'MongoError', code: 11000});
person.save();
```